# Restore focus to Java Applet when Browser/Tab gains focus

Tags: java, javascript, html, dom, applet

I have an applet running in a browser tab. When I switch to a different tab in the same browser, or ALT-TAB to another application entirely, the applet loses focus. When I return to the browser tab, the applet doesn't gain focus again. Is there a nice way to make this happen?

I assume it's a JavaScript change that's needed, not in the applet itself? Some onFocus handler perhaps? If it's relevant, our applet is created using an HTML `<applet>` tag.

Comment: Does the applet have to be embedded in a web page? If yes, why?

Comment: Because that's kind of the point of a web-based app! We _do_ offer a JNLP alternative too but most prefer the convenience of just entering the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe java has the `requestFocus()` method. It's  in the Component class, so your JPanel or whatever you are using may be able to use this.

For the javascript part, this is what a quick googling reveals: http://www.raditha.com/java/javascript.php. I hope it helps you!